# python - how to extract the nth element of a pandas dataframe and iterate without subscriptable problems

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I'm having a problem where I have a pandas dataframe where each column is a long list of strings split by whitespace. A sample dataframe column is shown here:

["{'type':", "'text/html',", "'language':", 'None,', "'base':", "'https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/04514242672909724721/7712142301995898267',",
}"]

For instance when I print this to a csv file that whole column listed above is in one excel cell

What I need to do is pull out the url from this column. The problem comes into play because I have a list of 20 of these columns and when I try to loop and do:

```
  for n, i in enumerate(list(x)):
        i[n] = i[n][5]
```

I get the error that 'float object is not subscriptable'.

I have seen many other questions similar to this but it seems that many don't deal with looping through. I know I need to take the 5th element of each column because when I checked df[x][0][5], I get 'https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/04514242672909724721/7712142301995898267'.

Any help on the best practices around this topic would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What you've shown looks nothing like a dataframe column. Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the question in python first before asking it. Your column is missing a quote. Let's fix it and name your column:

```
col = ["{'type':", "'text/html',", "'language':", 'None,', "'base':", "'https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/04514242672909724721/7712142301995898267'",", }"]
```

So now you are saying that this is actually a column in a DataFrame. Let's put this into a DataFrame to make the question reproducible:

```
df = DataFrame({'x':col})
```

You are saying that you have a number of these columns, and the 5th item is the URL that you are looking for. Then you can iterate over the columns and query the 5th element, and collect it in a list named URLs as follows:

```
URLs = []
for column in df:
    URLs.append(df[column][5])
```

---

After your comments, I think the structure is a bit different.

So you have **only 1 column**, and inside that column you have multiple rows. And the 5th element of each row is a URL you want to collect. Let's see if this mimics what you have (I made up 3 URL's):

```
row1 = ["{'type':", "'text/html',", "'language':", 'None,', "'base':", "'https://www.google.com/1'",", }"]
row2 = ["{'type':", "'text/html',", "'language':", 'None,', "'base':", "'https://www.google.com/2'",", }"]
row3 = ["{'type':", "'text/html',", "'language':", 'None,', "'base':", "'https://www.google.com/3'",", }"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [row1, row2, row3]})
```

which gives us:

```
In [352]: df
Out[352]: 
                                                 col
0  [{'type':, 'text/html',, 'language':, None,, '...
1  [{'type':, 'text/html',, 'language':, None,, '...
2  [{'type':, 'text/html',, 'language':, None,, '...
```

If that is the case, the solution is as simple as

```
In [353]: [e[5] for e in df['col']]
Out[353]: 
["'https://www.google.com/1'",
 "'https://www.google.com/2'",
 "'https://www.google.com/3'"]
```

Please comment if this does or doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Fatih - sorry for the first mistake. I had to text some info out and when i copied/pasted it deleted a quotation. I am close but the last code of URLs.append(df[column][5]) is giving the URL value 
URLs
Out[314]: 
[["{'type':",
  "'text/html',",
  "'language':",
  'None,',
  "'base':",
  "'https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/04514242672909724721/7712142301995898267',",
  "'value':",
  "'FIA",
  'arrests',
  'major',
  'gang',
  '<b>trafficking',
  'people</b>',
  'through',
  "Turbat'}"]]

Do you know why it is not just selecting the 5th item and also why it doesnt iterate?

Comment: I now get the correct URL but it only runs over the first row and doesn't iterate through all of the rows. The "col" has been initialized to have 70 rows of data with 70 different URLs in the column. The URL is only returning the first https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/04514242672909724721/7712142301995898267 value

Comment: So how many URL's do you have per column? I thought only one, and it is only in the 5th place per column. Isn't that the case?

Comment: The "col" field is one column. That column has 70 rows and each row has a different URL I need to pull out. I need to store the index as well so I can write the URL back to the original file for each row

Comment: I see, @EvanLuthringer. Let me edit my answer and you tell me if that answers your question.

Comment: Cool! I am glad!

Comment: @EvanLuthringer I appreciate it if you could click the checkmark sign next to my answer- that way we both get points. Thanks!